# Why won't LDAP client authenticate users

Tags: authentication, ldap, openldap

I have followed instructions here: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-configure-openldap-phpldapadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

and Added users as per https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-and-configure-ldap-account-manager-on-ubuntu-18-04-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

Correct config is returned by:
ldapsearch -x -h server.example.net -b "dc=example,dc=net"

But following https://www.tecmint.com/configure-ldap-client-to-connect-external-authentication/ the LDAP user just will not authenticated.
getent passwd user returns no output.

su - user
No passwd entry for user 'user'

please help

Comment: The second article looks quite bad. 1) Which instructions did you follow? The ones which describe nss-pam-ldapd, or the ones which describe the obsolete libnss-ldap? 2) What LDAP URI did you use – is it ldap:, ldaps;, or ldapi:?

Comment: steps 1 - 6 from https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-configure-openldap-phpldapadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/
then steps 1 - 4 from https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-and-configure-ldap-account-manager-on-ubuntu-18-04-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

For the server.


And for the client: Configure LDAP Client in Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 section of the tecmint link.

@grawity If you have links to better resources, I am happy to reverse my setup and run those instead?

Answer (score 0):

Could check /etc/ldap.conf?

uri is only enable ldapi. 
You must be enabled ldap and ldaps.

note. becaful ldapi///, ldap// and ldaps// 
count of '/' does not same.